# Using ADS1x15 library with ADS1114 in Python/Micropython

Tags: python, adafruit, micropython

I'm a little bit new with Micropython and a little experienced with Python3. I have a doubt about the compatibility between the ADS1114 16-bits ADC and the ADS1x15.py Adafruit's Library. This library was specifically design for the ADS1115 and the ADS1015, which both have mutliple ADC channels, but the ADS1114 just has 1 with the posibility for single-ended or differential analog readings.

So the Python [ADS1x15](https://github.com/robert-hh/ads1x15/blob/master/ads1x15.py) library goes like this(for full code click on the ADS1x15 link):

MULTIPLEXER MASK

[image]

And when it's time to read a differential analog value (i.e AIN0 - AIN1) , the function in charge of performing that task needs the channels from wher it will read):

Read Analog Value on Channel 1

[image]

According to page 28 in the ADS111x [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=SBAS444&fileType=pdf) on Table #2, 2nd line, 5th column, writing any value to those specific bits in the Configuration Register doesn't affect the ADS114.

Input Multiplexer Configuration

[image]

Should I use the ADS1x15 library or create a new one based on the allready existing one?

PS: This is my firts question here.

Comment: Have you considered raising an issue on github? Maybe the library developer has an appropriate answer. On a sidenote: reading from an A/D converter in a busy loop with a seemingly arbitrary sleep of 1mSec might cause trouble at one point.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I'll go to github for the developer's answer.

Comment: The library's author answered me on github and made a slight modification to the code.

Answer (score 1):

The author added two derived classes for the ADS1113 and ADS1114 and both of them use the almost the same methods as the regular original subclasses. 
[Link to the github raised issue.](https://github.com/robert-hh/ads1x15/issues/5)